# In Bash, what does !# means (exclamation mark and hashtag/pound)?

Tags: bash

why does this command give this output:

```
$ echo !#
echo echo
echo

$
```

I read about the !, how it negates or expands history, depending on context.
I just can't figure out why it behaves this way when joined with #.

Comment: Related: [Bash history in script: `!#:*`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149715/bash-history-in-script)

Answer (score 3):

When you execute `echo !#` what you are essentially saying is 'bash can you substitute the entire command line where !# is currently?(excluding !# itself)'

Bash will then print the result of this substitution to stderr which is how you see `echo echo`  and then the next line of output is simply the result of running `echo echo`  which is just `echo` in stdout.

This is detailed in the Event Designators section of the [manpage for bash](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash).

More or less `!#` is just a special event designator for having duplications of your command line

A more clear example;

```bsh
echo "There's two of us!";!#
```

Results in:

```
echo "There's two of us!";echo "There's two of us!"; 
There's two of us! 
There's two of us!
```